# Command `git status` does not show `(new commits)` for submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have standard top-level Git repository with Git submodules.

It is known that when commit id recorded by top-level repository does not match actual `HEAD` for specific submodule, `git status` from top-level repository reports it by `(new commits)` (for example):

```
modified:   submodule-a.git (new commits)
modified:   submodule-b.git (new commits)
```

### Problem

Now, in some circumstances, `git status` stops reporting `(new commits)` for just some of the submodules even if it is clear that there are new commits - 
it may incorrectly stop reporting `(new commits)` for `submodule-a.git` while still showing properly `(new commits)` for `submodule-b.git`.

I can verify that commit ids do not match:

- What top-level repository "thinks":

  ```
  > git ls-tree HEAD submodule-a.git
  160000 commit edff703c82e270afbabc4ac4b571fdbdaefd88bc  submodule-a.git
  ```
- What submodule repository "thinks":

  ```
  > cd submodule-a.git
  > git rev-parse HEAD
  1b66fb09ca9506f1b707fe28135cb3c07c2cd717
  ```
- By the way, both top-level and submodule repositories are otherwise have clean status:

  Top-level (note missing entry for `submodule-a.git`):

  ```
   > git status
   On branch master
   Changes not staged for commit:
     (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
     (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

           modified:   submodule-b.git (new commits)

   no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
   > git diff --submodule
   # [NO OUTPUT]
  ```

  Submodule:

  ```
   > cd submodule-a.git
   > git status
   On branch master
   nothing to commit, working directory clean
  ```

This is a problem because I'm also unable to update (as in `git add --all && git commit`) commit ids for such submodules recorded by top-level repository because it simply "thinks" there is nothing to update.

**Platform/Version:** GNU/Linux 4.2.6-200.fc22.x86_64, git version 2.4.3 (also confirmed on 2.5.0).

### Question

**Is it a bug or there is an option somewhere which may disable such `(new commits)` report?**

Comment: Can you add what git status outputs when run inside the submodule which is not showing new commits?

Comment: @mu無 - I've updated directly into the problem description. After some testing, I strongly believe it is a bug. However, I have not figured out simple steps to reproduce this problem. Git just turns into this state somehow.

Comment: any relevant/correct output with `git diff --submodule` command when run from top level?

Comment: @dopeddude, it's been too long... Added output for `git diff --submodule` in the top-level/parent repo = no output. The issue still persists. I guess I need to try to reproduce it in publicly available repository.

Comment: The issue disappeared when it was tested with Git `2.7.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-confirmed the issue. Then I (in-place) upgraded OS to recently released Fedora 24 (which has Git `2.7.4` by default) - the same filesystem content was preserved (repositories and configuration). And the issue disappeared.

So, it must have been a bug in previous versions of git.

---

One retrospective observation - I never managed to reproduce things manually using short branch names. The problem appeared in CI when many automatic branches were created over the time ~ 100 (one per build) with long names ~ 120+ characters. These condition might hit some unhandled edge cases in Git.

Answer (score 0):

(not an answer) I had a similar issue recently happen with git 2.23.0 on macOS mojave - git status is not showing status of submodules. I decided I'll just re-clone the project from scratch, while I was committing changes I switched the branch of my parent repo, and then all of the sudden submodule changes appeared. I switched back to our main dev branch, and the submodule changes were still being shown, so something about switching branches appeared to bust some sort of cache or something like that.